# How to retrieve, if mod_rewrite should rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a mod_rewrite. The given URLS should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-)$ index.php?anum=$1&aname=$2
```

The problem with that is, that it also rewrites things like javascript files matching the pattern, because they are in some subdirectories.

So how do I achieve, that mod-rewrite only accepts URLs like "foo/bar" and no URL like "fizz/buzz/jq.js"?

Answer (score 0):

You may ensure to not match existing files or directories by using the following rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-)$ index.php?anum=$1&aname=$2
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond for the full power of RewriteCond.

I often use

```
RewriteCond $1 !^favicon.ico|^css|^js
```

to exclude favicon, and the css and js directories from beeing rewritten.

The following should exclude Javascript and CSS files:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.css$|\.js$
```

Comment: Added a missing ! to last RewriteCond. 

A 500 indicates an error in your rewrite. The Apache error log may tell you more. Was is the RewriteCond you use?

Answer (score 0):

if you want

test/foo/dir/test44.j4s

to

dir test44.j4s

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)/(.*) index.php?dir=$1&file=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this thing: if the request doesn't end with a known extension, then apply the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(\.(css|js|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico))
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-)$ index.php?anum=$1&aname=$2
```

Or do it the opposite side: if the request *starts* with a known extension, then stops, otherwise keep on applying the rest:

```
RewriteRule (.*)(\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)){1}$ $1$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-)$ index.php?anum=$1&aname=$2
```

Both solutions should work.
Tell me which one did ;)
Olivier